# List comprehensions in FilterExpression in boto3 for Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, nosql

So I have some items in a database in dynamodb and it looks sort of like this, where name is the primary key

```
'name': {'S': 'bob'},
'users': {'L': [
    {'M': {
        'user_id': {'S': 'xxx'},
        'share': {'N': '1'}}},
    {'M': {
        'user_id': {'S': 'yyy'},
        'share': {'N': '4'}}}]}
```

Now my issue is that users is a list of dictionaries, and I'm wondering if there's any way I can scan the table to get the `name` when there is a specific `user_id` in it's list of users.

I know in python I'd do a list comprehension to just get a list of `user_id`'s and then just do a `user_id in [user['user_id'] for user in users]` and that would be the test, but I'm not sure how to do it in a DynamoDB scan `FilterExpression`.

I'm just trying to avoid the need for the Item to look like this:

```
'name': {'S': 'bob'},
'users': {'L': [
    {'M': {
        'user_id': {'S': 'xxx'},
        'share': {'N': '1'}}},
    {'M': {
        'user_id': {'S': 'yyy'},
        'share': {'N': '4'}}}]}
'user_ids': {'L': [
    {'S': 'xxx'},
    {'S': 'yyy'}]}
```

because it feels like a so called "code smell". But that would fix the problem as the filter expression would just be `:user_id in user_ids`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DynamoDB doesn't have a feature to filter the data present in the **Map inside the List data type**. The user list has user id and share attributes. If you know the values for both the user id and share, the **`CONTAINS`** operator can be used to filter the data.

Please note that as you mentioned in OP, the IN operator in DynamoDB can't be used like that. See the description below.

> IN : Checks for matching elements within two sets.
>
> AttributeValueList can contain one or more AttributeValue elements of type String,
>   Number, or Binary (not a set type). These attributes are compared
>   against an existing set type attribute of an item. If any elements of
>   the input set are present in the item attribute, the expression
>   evaluates to true.

```
var params = {
        TableName: "tablenames",    
        FilterExpression: "contains (#users, :usersDetails)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#users'  : 'users'},
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":usersDetails": {'user_id' : 'xxx', 'share' : 1}

        }
};
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it if I don't have the `share` value? Also thanks for the note on the IN operator. Didn't realize that!

Comment: Unfortunately, no way.

Comment: Is this still not possible ?